# The MainButton of the Telegram web-app does not work

Tags: javascript, web-applications, telegram

I'm using Google Apps to write a telegram bot and a web app. In the Telegram app on IPhone, the code works fine except for the `tg.sendData("string to send")` method - the button is clicked but sendData doesn't fire, the sent message is "string to send" is not displayed in the bot. In the desktop version of Telegram on Windows, the MainButton button is not displayed at all. Also, the `click` event of the `btn` button does not work and, accordingly, the `tg.MainButton.hide()`, `tg.MainButton.show()` methods do not work.

Tell me, please, what could be the matter?

```
const webApps = `https://script.google.com/macros/s/**KEY**/exec?chatID=**CHAT_ID**`
const web_app_info = { url: webApps }
const KB_WEB_APP = {
  keyboard: [
    [{
      text: "Моя кнопка",
      web_app: web_app_info
    }]
  ],
  resize_keyboard: true,
  one_time_keyboard: true
}

function botSendKeyboard(chat_id, text, keyboard = KB_WEB_APP) {
  let data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      chat_id: String(chat_id),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(tgAPI + "/sendMessage", data)
}
```

```
function doGet(e) {
 let htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index1.html')
 htmlOutput.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
 return htmlOutput
}
```

Код index1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Telegram WebApps</title>  
  <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Заголовок</p>
  <button id="btn" class="button">Show/Hide Main Button</button>
</body>

<script>

   let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
   tg.MainButton.text = "My Text";
   tg.MainButton.show()

   let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

   btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if (tg.MainButton.isVisible){
         tg.MainButton.hide()
      }
      else tg.MainButton.show()
   });

   window.Telegram.WebApp.onEvent("mainButtonClicked", function(){
      tg.sendData("some string that we need to send"); 
   });

</script>
</html>
```